# Как забрать коммиты с одной ветки на другую?

Tags: git

Добрый день. Вопрос: как слить из нижнего дерева(не знаю как назвать) все ответвления(ветки) на `master` - 2 самых верхних коммита? Сохранив при этом комментарии.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое разделение получено через `git rebase -i -root` -хотел переименовать самый первый коммит, переименовал. Только он создался как новый(пушнул через -f), поэтому и ожидаемо, что у предыдущих веток одно основание было, а стало теперь другое.

Через `git pull` ругается:

```
$ git pull origin branchOne
From https://bitbucket.org/s191k/for_my_own_work
 * branch            branchOne  -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: PS увидел git cherry-picking <SHA> - но дает скопировать только пустой коммит.

Comment: *--allow-unrelated-histories* добавьте

Comment: `хотел переименовать самый первый коммит... Только он создался как новый` – коммиты нельзя менять, они иммутабельны, можно только пересоздать похожий.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, задумывался над этим.

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо за команды, интересные.

Answer (score 1):

Раз у Вас такая интересная ситуация, тогда и решать ее нужно интересным способом. Вначале переключаетесь на оригинальную ветку и делаете так

```
git show -u <sha> > patch.diff
```

и так для другого коммита (только имя файла не забудьте подставить другой)

Теперь, когда патчи есть, можно переключиться на другую ветку, где нужно их применить. И делаем

```
git apply patch.diff
```

если кофликтов нет, то можно просто коммитить, иначе, нужно будет решить конфликт. И соответственно и с другим файлом дифа.

Внутри файла дифф хранится изменения в специальном формате, где указанно, какие строки удалить, а какие добавить, что бы получить нужные изменения. В принципе, это почти тот же cherry-pick, только ручками. Этим способом можно дифы переносить и между различными компьютерами.

Comment: Не могу сказать что уверен(ветки находятся на удаленном доступе, а про раюоту на удаленном доступе как-то пару слов), забрал с ветки коммит в патч, зашел назад на master, применил патч - но он пишет что такие файлы есть. https://gyazo.com/ca39338891d54c814b5baa44a72df64d

Либо я все же не на ветке был, либо не работает.

Comment: Проверьте "ручками", что нужные изменения подтянулись. Скорее всего, Вы не очень. Удачно взяли коммиты - возможно, они создают файлы, а в целевой ветке эти файлы уже есть.

Comment: *man git format-patch*?

Comment: @KoVadim, я и не говорю что я очень, я с git-ом только месяц разбираюсь. Окей попробую понять, что значит ручками проверить что те файлы. Если это про Status/diff и другие просмотры, то по факту файлы всегда будут одинаковые, только начинка будет меняться.

Comment: @sank, не переживайте,  вышенаписанное в ответе тоже *не очень* ;)

Comment: @0andriy, вообще проездился туда сюда по всем элементам, но да самое простое решение :

Вообщем как восстановить дерево, делаем фотку всего дерева ( all branches), нам нужны все SHA коммитов. После этого удаляем все ветки - в bitbucket . Теперь проверяем что у нас всего одна ветка - мастер , и делаем git reset --soft SHA коммита , это действие подтянет и предка ( т.е. и init и tesk tasks) , делаем git push -f, на bitbuckete создаём ветку с нужным названием и так пока не восстпновитесь.

Comment: @0andriy, 
К сожалению раз уже так запушил,  просто изменить коммент коммита уже не получится, понимаю что это безопасность, но жаль))
Спасибо за команды!